# Error in setting up flutter_localizations package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I need to add  `flutter_localizations` package to use Arabic language in my application, but when I add it in pubspec.yaml, it gives me the following error:

```
    Because calendar_timeline >=0.6.1 depends on intl ^0.16.1 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, calendar_timeline >=0.6.1 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
So, because elderly_app depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and calendar_timeline ^0.7.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because elderly_app depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and calendar_timeline ^0.7.0, version solving failed.)
```

This is my pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  calendar_timeline: ^0.7.0
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.0
  date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.1
  hijri: ^2.0.3
  flutter_week_view: ^1.0.0+2
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
```

It works when I delete the lines under `flutter_localizations` like `cupertino_icons` and `calendar_timeline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the above message you should decrease your `calendar_timeline` version to lower than `0.6.1`. for example `calendar_timeline: 0.6.0`

and add this line to `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.16.0
```

[image]

Comment: I have changed it, but also there is an error:

Because calendar_timeline >=0.6.1 depends on intl ^0.16.1 and calendar_timeline >=0.3.0 <0.6.1 depends on intl ^0.16.0, calendar_timeline >=0.3.0 requires intl ^0.16.0.
And because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with calendar_timeline >=0.3.0.
So, because elderly_app depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and calendar_timeline ^0.6.0, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1

Comment: I suggest you another way. I edited my answer.

Comment: if you use calendar_timeline: ^0.7.0 you should override  intl: ^0.16.1

Comment: where should I add dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.16.0?


under dependencies:?

Comment: Yes. I added picture too.

Comment: Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:
! intl 0.16.1 (0.17.0 available)

Comment: that is warning not problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating all of your packages to the latest version.